# параллельная запись в таблицы sqlite3 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite3

Всем привет. Всех с выходными и наступившими праздниками!
У меня возникла потребность в параллельной записи таблиц в одну бд. Но столкнулся в проблемой ее реализации. Есть код который создает бд(если таковая отсутствует), создает таблицу и записывает в нее данные через проверку:

```
#Создает новый файл , если он есть то просто подключается
base = sqlite3.connect('new_base4.db')
#Класс для создания, чтения, изменения таблиц

cur = base.cursor()
#Создание таблицы
base.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_eurusd(time PRIMARY KEY, last, bid, ask, value, flag, real_volume)")

vrema = 0
#Повтор кода для исполнения
tempo = time.time() + 1000000000000
while time.time() < tempo:
    tick = mt5.symbol_info_tick('EURUSD_i')

    last = tick.last
    bid = tick.bid
    ask = tick.ask
    value = tick.volume
    flag = tick.flags
    value_real = tick.volume_real

    if vrema == tick.time_msc:  # если переменная равна предыдущему значению
        continue  # Начинаем цикл заново

    vrema = tick.time_msc  # Иначе всё нормально, продолжаем в штатном режиме

    # Заполнение значением в таблицу. Кол-во ?? соответствует кол-ву столбцов
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO data_eurusd VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",(vrema, last, bid, ask, value, flag, value_real))# Значения
    base.commit()
    # print(f"TIME_ms:{tick.time_msc}, EURUSD:{tick.last}, цена BID:{tick.bid}, цена ASK:{tick.ask}, объем:{tick.volume}, FLAG:{tick.flags}, REAL:{tick.volume_real} ", end='\n')
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Так вот на чем встал. Создал 41 таблицу по методу ctrlC ctrlV, а вот при параллельной записи ничего не получается. Также не могу понять как присвоить нужные данные в нужную таблицу. Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы шла запись во все таблицы. В данный момент пишется только одна. Буду рад небольшому куску кода для большего понимания.

Comment: если говорить очень кратко - sqlite не поддерживает параллельную запись, только параллельное чтение

Comment: окей... тогда для реализация на sqlite не подходит, может какая другая библиотека поможет? если есть таковые?

Comment: Из бесплатных баз данных - PostgreSQL, MariaDB, MongoDB (но это скорее для документо-ориентированых БД)

Comment: спасибо, буду рассматривать каждую и искать нужную мне